# Ensure that the sum of two randomly generated numbers is equal to the sum of another two randomly generated numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I am writing a program that calculates the turning forces (moments) on a uniform rod (where the centre of mass is in the middle). I need to split the length of the rod into four values, which themselves don't have to be equal; however, the sum of the first two values must equal the sum of the last two values. The total length of the rod must be randomly generated - so how do I do this?

Here is how I am randomly generating the numbers:

```
random_value_one = random.uniform(1, 5)
random_value_two = random.uniform(1, 5)
random_value_three = random.uniform(1, 5)
random_value_four = random.uniform(1, 5)
total_length_of_rod = random_value_one + random_value_two + random_value_three + random_value_four
centre_of_mass = total_length_of_rod / 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short your fourth value is not actually random.  So, you can generate the first two and compute the sum.  Then generate the third one in the range of that sum.  The fourth value is the difference.  You can also work from the total length or half lengths that you split randomly.

```
import random

# option1: random 1st and 2nd, 3rd splits total, fourth is difference
rv1 = random.uniform(1, 5)
rv2 = random.uniform(1, 5)
sumOfFirst2 = rv1 + rv2
rv3 = random.uniform(1, sumOfFirst2-1)
rv4 = sumOfFirst2 - rv3

print("Option1:")
print(rv1,rv2,rv1+rv2)
print(rv3,rv4,rv3+rv4)

# option 2: random total length, split each half randomly
totalLength = random.uniform(4,20)
sumOfFirst2 = totalLength/2
rv1         = random.uniform(1,sumOfFirst2-1)
rv2         = sumOfFirst2 - rv1
rv3         = random.uniform(1,sumOfFirst2-1)
rv4         = sumOfFirst2 - rv3

print("Option2:")
print(rv1,rv2,rv1+rv2)
print(rv3,rv4,rv3+rv4)

# option 3: random half length, split each side
sumOfFirst2 = random.uniform(2,10)
rv1         = random.uniform(1,sumOfFirst2-1)
rv2         = sumOfFirst2 - rv1
rv3         = random.uniform(1,sumOfFirst2-1)
rv4         = sumOfFirst2 - rv3

print("Option3:")
print(rv1,rv2,rv1+rv2)
print(rv3,rv4,rv3+rv4)

# option 4: random extermities, random sum of center parts then split center
rv1         = random.uniform(1,5)
rv4         = random.uniform(1,5)
center      = random.uniform(2,10)
totalLength = center+rv1+rv4
rv2         = totalLength/2 - rv1 
rv3         = totalLength/2 - rv4

print("Option4:")
print(rv1,rv2,rv1+rv2)
print(rv3,rv4,rv3+rv4)
```

output:

```
Option1:
3.8733926704150394 1.2002268887772458 5.073619559192285
3.840231922558826 1.2333876366334593 5.073619559192285

Option2:
3.547962226731686 1.2866434919683414 4.834605718700027
1.52708327731985 3.3075224413801774 4.834605718700027

Option3:
5.271438412416368 3.9102475112312245 9.181685923647592
2.116625606537367 7.065060317110225 9.181685923647592

Option4:
2.0745608124206196 4.236051851683254 6.310612664103874
4.163042898863589 2.1475697652402848 6.310612664103873
```

If you are concerned about distributions, you can chose the method that fits your requirements best.

Comment: Excellent - wish I'd thought of that! Thank you!

Comment: @SendViaAirmail not sure how excellent it is, but marginal distributions are quite different. Is it really what you want? Total length distribution looking a bit off as well

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get all pairs of numbers with the correct sum and then choose one randomly.

```
import random
r1 = random.randrange(1, 6)
r2 = random.randrange(1, 6)
pairs = [x for x in [(i, j) for i in range(1, 6) for j in range(1, 6)] if sum(x) == r1 + r2]
r3, r4 = random.choice(pairs)
total_length_of_rod = r1 + r2 + r3 + r4
centre_of_mass = total_length_of_rod / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this logic? Generate the first two random numbers and add them up. Then generate the third random number, and test if it is less than the addition of the first two. if it is, the last random number will be [(the addition of the first two) - (the third random number)]. If it is not, generate the third random number again. This ensures that it's possible to add to the same length (if the third number was larger, it would not be possible). The 4th number isn't randomly generated, but it is random in the sense that the third number is random and it has to equal the sum of the first two so the last number doesn't really have a choice.

This way you avoid nested loops and improve efficiency :)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you where you need:

```
random_sum = random.uniform(1, 5)
random_value_one = random.uniform(1, random_sum)
random_value_two = random_sum - random_value_one

random_value_three = random.uniform(1, random_sum)
random_value_four = random_sum - random_value_three
```

Comment: Do you recognize that if values are in the range [1...5], sum would be in the range [2...10]?

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole thing in a function you can call, then at the end have an if loop. Check if ((rod1 + rod2) == (rod3 + rod4)) and if not then call the function to restart it. In addition (or if python doesn't let logic like that work) you might need to declare new variables that are rod1 + rod2 and rod3 + rod4, then compare their values.

Comment: It's already in a callable function - I just didn't put that bit of code in the question because it's quite lengthy and I didn't want to clog up the question details.